# Why is my render result disappearing after denoising?

Tags: render-layers, compositing-nodes, denoise

I wanted to denoise my image in compositing. I don't know why it is disappearing after connecting with denoiser.
[image]

Edit:
I solved deactivating *Progressive Refine*
from *Render Properties > Performance > Tiles*