# Denoising in Blender results in a black screen (Render layer node is connected)?

Tags: compositing-nodes, denoise

So I've seen a lot of people complain about their experience using the compositor. Usually people forget to actually connect render layers to the output. However, I have not forgotten this, yet it still turns black *sometimes*. Not always, but not at predictable times. Has anyone experienced this issue?

Also, connecting the render layers directly to composite results in a perfectly fine image. It is only when connecting to the denoise node that the screen jumps to black. I use Blender 2.82a.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). There was a very similar question recently https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/174063/. Perhaps it's a bug in 2.82?

Comment: I'm thinking it might be yes. I'm sorry I really did search for similar questions but I missed that one.

Comment: Well, you can report it as a bug through *Help > Report a bug* in Blender :).

Comment: I will, thank you for your help.